# Ios11 Changing Calendar From Gregorian To japanese or Buddhist Crash?

Tags: iphone, swift, datepicker, calendar, ios11

```
var datePickerView: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker() 
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
initializeBarButtons() }
func initializeBarButtons() {  
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date // This is the line that gets the error
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EmployeeDetailEditViewController.handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged) 
  }
```

This commented line is causing the crash when the calendar is changed from Gregorian to Buddhist.

Crash : -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 1]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18626e364 0x1854b4528 0x186206e9c 0x186136840 0x18f9a1890 0x1902238a8 0x19022045c 0x1902210f4
>   0x19022139c 0x190214254 0x1902136cc 0x190213c08 0x190213d24
>   0x1013881e0 0x101386d1c 0x101387018 0x18f768590 0x18f768304
>   0x18f8d2bd4 0x18f7f5c4c 0x18f7f5890 0x18f7f5790 0x1a53e4c18
>   0x18f74cf00 0x18a2b1998 0x18a2b5b20 0x18a22236c 0x18a249b90
>   0x18a24a9d0 0x186215edc 0x186213894 0x186213e50 0x186133e58
>   0x187fe0f84 0x18f7b367c 0x10131b378 0x185c5056c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

How to Solve This ?

Comment: First you need to show more code so that we can see the use of the line in context.  It's very difficult to look at a single (or two) line of code and tell what the error is.

Comment: Updated @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: I have edited the question to fix the code formatting for you.  However what I would really need to see is how the date picker itself is setup.

Comment: i have edited Code Any More info needed @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Do you do nothing else with the picker like add it to a view, configure any other settings.  If I just create a default picker, add it to my view and set it's frame I works with the Gregorian and Buddhist calendars.  Are you changing the calendar in the iOS settings before running the app?

Comment: after running the app Changing the calendar and same issue is with before changing the calendar . It works perfectly with ios 10 but ios 11 causes crash  i have also included the selector function  . @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: I think you need to show every bit of code related to the date picker.  How are you adding it to a view to be displayed? Are you configuring anything else about it because I can't get it to go wrong.

Comment: textField.inputView = datePickerView   Just Set this @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163183/discussion-between-amey-and-upholder-of-truth).

Comment: Ok I created a simple test project with a single `UITextField` and setup as you have said.  I run it for the Gregorian calendar then quit and run it again with the Buddhist calendar and it works for both.  I tried this in the simulator for iPhone 8, iPhone X and iPad.

Comment: Crash is not occurring on simulator . Please check on actual device . @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Ok I'm in the office at the moment so the time I have devote to this is low but hopefully we have added some extra details that will help get the question answered.  I will look into it further when I get time.

Comment: ok . Pls Update if any solution found @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth did you find any solution since I am also getting the same crash?

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to test it as I've spent the last few days downloading and installing over 40GB of test data in the simulator which at some point I need to upload to my iPhone (neither work iPads have enough storage).  I will try to take another look today.

Comment: @atul  I've just tried my test app on my iPhone 8 and it worked fine.  Do you have a test project you could share that has the problem (dropbox, git, etc)

Comment: Hi guys,
any solution around this?

Comment: @Rohit  i used                                                                                            
     if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            self.datePickerView.calendar = gregorianCalendar
        }
        else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        } .    Temporary Solution To Forcefully Set calendar as gregorian

Comment: @Amey but why we needed the check for iOS 11? As gregorianCalendar is available in iOS 7+

Comment: I added Because that line was causing crash in Ios 11 only . So to set calendar forcefully in ios 11 to gregorian @Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't solve it, as there is an open radar on it (https://openradar.appspot.com/41120005).
Meanwhile, use @Amey workaround:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { 
    let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian) 
    self.datePickerView.calendar = gregorianCalendar 
} else { 
    // Fallback on earlier versions 
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. still crashing on datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date when phone calendar is set to Buddhist

Comment: I was facing a crash when the region is Singapore and the calendar is Buddhist. when its United states and Buddhist there was not crash.

Comment: datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") I was missing this line now region is standardised